# Rendezvous ADA - how it works

Tags: task, ada, multitasking

I'm trying to understand how the R-V in ADA works:

**server (pseudo)code:**

```
task test is
  entry put (num: in integer);
  entry get (num: out integer);
end test;

task body test is
  local_num: integer;
begin
  accept put (num: in integer) do
    local_num := num;
  end put;

  // some next processing of local_num, eg:
  local_num := local_num * 2;

  accept get (num: out integer) do
    num := local_num;
  end get;
end test;
```

and the client a server are communicating as following:

```
client (a)    | server (b)
================================
              |   // sleep
(call_entry)  |   // sleep
a.put(num)    |   // sleep
  // sleep    | (accept_entry)
  // sleep    | b.accept put(num)
  // sleep    | local_num := num;
  // sleep    | local_num := local_num * 2;
              |   ???   <--------------------- what is happening after that point?
(call_entry)  |   // sleep
a.get(num)    |   // sleep
  // sleep    | (accept_entry)
  // sleep    | b.accept get(num)
```

- Is it correct?
- Can you describe me how it continues?
- Who awakes the client to get the result? How the client know, that it can get the result?

**update:** (correct process?)

```
client        | server (test)
================================
test.put(num) |   // sleep      ----------> call entry
test.get(A)   | accept put(num) ----------> accept entry PUT (call entry GET to the QUEUE)
  // sleep    | local_num := num;
  // sleep    | local_num := local_num * 2;
test.get(A)   | accept get(A)   ----------> accept entry (removed from the QUEUE)
              |   // sleep
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ada Rendez-Vous are really simple, in fact you have a task `test` with 2 entries `get` and `put`. Once you run the program, the `test` task is started, so the `local_num` value is created (with no defined initial value) and the `body` is executed BUT the first statement is an `accept` so the task is waiting for an entry call.

```
procedure ... is

    task test is 
       ...
    end test ;

    task body test is
       ...
    end test ;

    A : Integer ;

begin
    -- 1. The 'test' task is started here, waiting for a call to `put`
    -- 2. You call the 'put' entry, which mean that the current task (the main task) 
    --    is stopped until the end of the entry call.
    test.put(33) ;
    -- 3. Here the entry 'put' is finished, so the 2 tasks are executing
    --    simultaneously
    -- 4. Here we call the 'get' entry, there is a non predictive behaviour: 
    --    We do not know if the instruction local_num := local_num * 2; has
    --    been executed or not, so 2 case:
    --     - The instruction has been executed, so the 'test' task is waiting
    --       and directly accept the 'get' entry, while the main task wait
    --     - The instruction has not been executed, so the main 'task' wait
    --       until there is someone to accept is call
    --    What you're sure is that the entry 'get' won't be executed before
    --    the instruction, and that someone calling 'get' will have to wait
    --    until the 'test' task get to the 'accept get' instruction.
    test.get(A) ;
    -- 5. Here, the 'get' entry is finished, so you're sure that you have ended
    --    the 'test' task

end ... ;
```

In fact, when you call a entry like `test.get`, you loose the control until the `test.get` entry has been fully executed. If there is no task waiting for this entry, you will wait until a task request this entry.

```
procedure BadTask is

    -- Stupid task that will accept a 'put' entry and then a 'get' (only once)
    task T is
        entry get (A : out Integer);
        entry put (A : in Integer);
    end T ;

    task body T is
        LocalInteger : Integer := 0 ;
    begin
        accept put (A : in Integer) do
            LocalInteger := A ;
        end put ;
        accept get (A : ouInteger) do
            A := LocalInteger ;
        end get ;
    end T ;

    A : Integer ;
begin
    -- Here T is waiting for 'put'
    T.get (A) ; 
    -- You will never get here and your program is blocked because the two tasks
    -- are waiting but no one can't get the control.
end BadTask ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And to point 4 (I still don't understand it) - For example, THE instruction has not been executed yet and my code is `test.put(33); test.get(A);`, so the client has to wait. How he's waiting? Passive (sleep - but how is awaken?) or active (some kind of spinlock)?

Comment: @gaffcz The client will sleep (no spinlock), as when calling `test.put(33)`. he will be awaken at the end of the `get` entry, by an implementation defined method (something managed by the underlying operating system). The client does not call `get` in a loop until it's accepted, the `get` call is pushed into a queue, and when the `test` task reach the `accept get` instruction, it first looks into the queue before waiting (if there is no call in the queue, he sleeps until being awaken by a call).

Comment: Aha, it's much cleaner now. Thank you very much, Holt!